# Can anyone cast Guidance from a Pendant of the Occult?

Tags: spells, magic-items, pathfinder-2e

Can a Fighter with a [Pendant of the Occult](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=450) invested cast Guidance, even if he normally does not have the Cast a Spell activity?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. The Pendant of the Occult grants the user an innate spell, and [innate spells can be cast even if the user isn't a member of a spellcasting class](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=279).

Comment: How did I miss the _innate_ part?

Comment: It happens to the best of us!